# What could be the meaning of " Aut$(X)$- invariant vertex colouring "

Tags: terminology, graph-isomorphism

Aut$(X) = \{\sigma \mid X^\sigma = X\}$, where $\sigma : X \mapsto X$ is a bijective map.

I am not getting the meaning of " Aut$(X)$- invariant vertex colouring".

I know the meaning of invariant means that does not change. So did it mean that suppose vertices of graph $X$ are colored than if we consider the group action of Aut$(X)$ on the vertices set of $X$ then it will preserve the color?

**Motivation** : I encounter this term while reading the some research paper related to graph and hyper-graph isomorphism.

Comment: A coloring $\phi:V(X) \to C$ for some (presumably finite) set of colors $C$ such that $\phi(fv) = \phi(v)$ for every graph automorphism $f:X \to X$.

Comment: I think that your reading is correct: each colored component is permuted by the permutations that are graph automorphisms.